# MDL and content columns

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid, material-design

I understand how we do this in bootstrap, but I am wondering how we do the following in MDL.

BOOTSTRAP Code:

```
 <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          One of three columns
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
          One of three columns
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I am wondering if someone could please show a MDL example that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

[MDL Official explanation](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#layout-section/grid)

```
<div class="mdl-grid">
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col-phone"></div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col-phone"></div>
  <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-col-phone"></div>
</div>
```

Similar to bootstrap the column width is 12 total.  I believe you are looking for mdl-cell--N-col-phone, (  Sets the column size for the cell to N in phone mode only).